# how to run asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have to load two large files in parallels
so far I have this code

The code below is click button method

```
private async void MILoadLogFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{       
    ...
    if (oFD.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        await myLogSession.LoadCompassLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
        await myLogSession.LoadCoreServiceLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
    }
}
```

loading method:

```
public async Task LoadCompassLogAsync(String fileName)
{
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
    if (fileName.Contains("Compass"))
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            using (streamReader)
            {
                //Console.Out.WriteLine("lineCount: " + lineCount);
                while (((line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                       && !CompassLogLoadCompleted)
                {
                    ...
                    loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl(eLoggingLvl);
                    CompassLogData cLD = new CompassLogData(id, dateTime, loggingLvl, threadId, loggingMessage);

                    await addRoCompassLogCollectionAsync(cLD);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

the `LoadCoreServiceLogAsync` is almost identical to `LoadCompassLogAsync`.

The two loading methods runs sequentially. I want them to run in parallel.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will run one task after the other. To run the two tasks in parallel you can use the [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) method:

```
var loadCompassLogTask = myLogSession.LoadCompassLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
var loadCoreServiceLogTask = myLogSession.LoadCoreServiceLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
Task.WaitAll(loadCompassLogTask, loadCoreServiceLogTask);
```

Or if you want to use `await` you can use [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374.aspx):

```
var loadCompassLogTask = myLogSession.LoadCompassLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
var loadCoreServiceLogTask = myLogSession.LoadCoreServiceLogAsync(oFD.FileName);
await Task.WhenAll(loadCompassLogTask, loadCoreServiceLogTask);
```

Comment: +1 for the second option which would be preferable given this appears to be called from the UI thread.

Comment: @Daniel Kelley,is it possible to use second option without using UI Thread?

Comment: @pars What I meant was that you call both methods from the UI thread (you respond to a click event). However, by using `await Task.WhenAll` you will not block the UI thread. I believe the first option would cause the UI thread to be blocked.

Comment: @Daniel Kelley, I just tried the second option and the UI is very very slow. any solution to that?

Comment: @pars You should probably ask the person who posted this answer :) My knowledge of the new async featuers are limited and I don't have a version of VS that allows me to use them.